# Using XPATH to get the node location to retrieve another value from the same tree

Tags: xml, xpath

I got an xml file that I need to work on (adding it in the end of the post).
I need the retrieve the node “DocIDAutoNumerator” only when I find the node “DocumentTypeValue” = 1319.
Is there a way to look it in just one XPATH?
or should I look for DocumentTypeValue ==1319 and get the current position so I can make a XPATH using the location I just retrieved?
Thank you all for your help!

the file is -

```
    <Document>
       <Labels>
          <Label>
             <Fields>
                <Field>
                   <Code>DocumentTypeValue</Code>
                   <Value>4008</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                   <Code>DocIDAutoNumerator</Code>
                   <Value>123121</Value>
                </Field>
             </Fields>
          </Label>
       </Labels>
      <ActivityTime>2021-08-11 </ActivityTime>
    </Document>

    <Document>
       <Labels>
          <Label>
             <Fields>
                <Field>
                   <Code>DocumentTypeValue</Code>
                   <Value>1319</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                   <Code>DocIDAutoNumerator</Code>
                   <Value>21321</Value>
                </Field>
             </Fields>
          </Label>
       </Labels>
    </Document>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//Fields[Field[Code="DocumentTypeValue"][Value="1319"]]
 /Field[Code="DocIDAutoNumerator"]/Value
```

selects `Value` element of a `Field` which

- has a `"DocIDAutoNumerator"` `Code`, and
- is in the same `Fields` element with a `Field` that

  - has a `"DocumentTypeValue"` `Code` and has a `"1319"` `Value`.

Comment: Hi, This soultion wroked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

To get the `<Field>` node that contains the `<Code>` element with the value "DocIDAutoNumerator" having a `Field/Code` sibling with the value "1319" you can use the following XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//Field[Code='DocIDAutoNumerator' and ../Field[Value='1319']]
```

This returns the `<Field>` element with the required properties.
To get its `Value`, append the String `/Value` to the expression.
And to retrieve its `Code` element, append the String `/Code`.

Comment: Hi, thank for for your help! but sadly I couldn't make it work with what you wrote above but someone else solution worked!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
//Document[.//Code/text() = "DocumentTypeValue"/following-sibling::Value/text() = "1319"]////Code/text() = "DocIDAutoNumerator"/following-sibling::Value/text()
```

Comment: Hi, thank for for  your help! but sadly I couldn't make it work with what you wrote above but someone else solution worked!

Comment: OK, no problem!