# XPath with multiple conditions at multiple levels?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a xml file which I need to retrieve the node "DocIDAutoNumerator" value but I only need to take it if the filed "ActivityTime" contains the date of today (2021-08-11) lets say  and if the node "DocumentTypeValue" equals 1319.
I was trying for hours but can mange to retrieve it with what I did.
This is what I did -

### XPath

```
//Document[.//Field[Code[text()='DocumentTypeValue'] and Value[text()='1319']] and //ActivityTime[contains(text(),'2021-08-11')] ]//Fields[Field[Code="DocumentTypeValue"]]  /Field[Code="DocIDAutoNumerator"]/Value
```

### XML

```
 <root>
    <Document>
       <Labels>
          <Label>
             <Fields>
                <Field>
                   <Code>DocumentTypeValue</Code>
                   <Value>4008</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                   <Code>DocIDAutoNumerator</Code>
                   <Value>123121</Value>
                </Field>
             </Fields>
          </Label>
       </Labels>
      <ActivityTime>2021-08-11 </ActivityTime>
    </Document>
    <Document>
       <Labels>
          <Label>
             <Fields>
                <Field>
                   <Code>DocumentTypeValue</Code>
                   <Value>1319</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                   <Code>DocIDAutoNumerator</Code>
                   <Value>21321</Value>
                </Field>
             </Fields>
          </Label>
       </Labels>
      <ActivityTime>1993-08-11 </ActivityTime>
    </Document>
 </root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
/root/Document[normalize-space(ActivityTime)='2021-08-11']
     //Fields[Field/Code='DocumentTypeValue']
      /Field[Code='DocIDAutoNumerator']/Value/text()
```

selects the text of the targeted `Value`,

```
123121
```

as requested.

### Explanation

1. Select `Document` based on the given `ActivityTime` value.

   - Use `normalize-space()` to eliminate variances to do, in this case, trailing whitespace.
2. From there, select `Fields` based on the given `Field/Code` value.
3. From there, select the `Field based on the given` Code` value.
4. Select that `Field` element's `Value` child's text.

### Related

- [Using XPATH to get the node location to retrieve another value from the same tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70022052/290085)

---

### Update:

To also add that the `Field` with a `DocumentTypeValue` `Code` must have a `4008` `Value`:

```
/root/Document[normalize-space(ActivityTime)='2021-08-11']
        //Fields[Field[Code='DocumentTypeValue'][Value='4008']]
         /Field[Code='DocIDAutoNumerator']/Value/text()
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! but I need also the "DocumentTypeValue" equals 1319 condition to be added to the XPATH.

Comment: @FM_Bendo:  Are you sure?  There is no `Document` that has both a `DocumentTypeValue` of `1319` and an `ActivityTime` of `2021-08-1` in your sample.

Comment: @FM_Bendo: I've updated the answer to show how to do what you ask but for a `DocumentTypeValue` of `4008`, which is present in your sample.  From this pattern, you should be able to adapt to other variations as you may come to need.

Comment: Thank you it worked!
Do you have a good website of learning more of the XPATH?

Comment: You're welcome.  Michael Kay's XSLT book teaches XPath well.  Also, the [W3C XPath 1.0 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/)  is remarkably readable.

Answer (score 1):

This (admittedly convoluted) xpath expression

```
//Document[contains(.//ActivityTime,"2021-08-11")]  \
[.//Field[.//Code[.="DocumentTypeValue"]][.//Value[.="4008"]]]   \
//Field[./Code[.="DocIDAutoNumerator"]]/Value
```

should output, given your example xml

```
123121
```

Comment: This also works (+1) but can be simplified in places: `[./e ...]` can be written as `[e ...]` and `f[e[.='val']]` as `f[e='val']`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! 
When I am running it in one line it doesn't work...